# Uniform vs normal convergence - meaning

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

My textbook defined 3 types of convergence for a function series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ with $f_n:I\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$:

1)”pointwise convergence for an $x\in I$” $\iff$ the numerical series obtained by evaluating $f_n(x)$ is convergent

2)”uniformly convergent in $I$” $\iff$ $\lim_{k\to\infty}(\sup(f(x)_{x\in I}-\sum_{n=0}^kf_n(x)))=0$.

3)”totally convergent in $I$” $\iff$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sup _{x \in I} |f_n(x)|$ converges. I found that this definition is, in english, called “normal convergence”.

We also said that normal convergence implies uniform convergence which implies pointwise convergence.

**QUESTIONS**

Q1) The sum function $f(x)$ should be defined just by saying that the function series convergence in each $x \in I$, and we assing to each $x$ the value of pointwise convergence of the function series in $x$ itself. Then, uniform convergence is useful for example because it implies that $f(x)$ is continue in $I$ (with the hypothesis that the $f_n$ are continuos in $I$). So what is the normal convergence for? How is its meaning different than uniform convergence? I know that for example, the two are equivalent for power series

Q2) I have found another definition, also named “total convergence”, which is “there exists a positive numerical sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\forall x\in I ( \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:|f_n(x)|\leq a_n$ and the numerical series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges”. Is this actually equivalent to the normal convergence, or is it equivalent to the uniform one, or is it different? I can’t understand it

Comment: I believe you are looking for the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), which is a sufficient condition to establish uniform convergence.

Comment: @interspazia thank you, can you also help me with Q1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of uniform convergence shouldn't have the $ \forall _ { x \in I } $ part; the variable $ x $ is bound by the supremum, which is a supremum over $ x \in I $.  Also, in the second version of total convergence, I believe that you want $ { \lvert f _ n { ( x ) } \rvert } \leq a _ n $ instead of $ { \lvert a _ n \rvert } \leq f _ n { ( x ) } $, partly because $ a _ n $ is assumed positive but $ f _ n { ( x ) } $ is not, and partly because with the reverse inequality, $ f $ could take arbitrarily large values and the sum could easily diverge.

So we have these four definitions:

- pointwise convergence: for each $ x \in I $, $ \sum \limits _ { n = 0 } ^ \infty f _ n { ( x ) } $ converges.
- uniform convergence: for some function $ f $ on $ I $, $ \lim \limits _ { k \to \infty } \sup \limits _ { x \in I } { \biggl ( f ( x ) - \sum \limits _ { n = 0 } ^ k f _ n { ( x ) } \biggr ) } $ converges to $ 0 $;
- normal convergence: $ \sum \limits _ { n = 0 } ^ \infty \sup \limits _ { x \in I } { \lvert f _ n { ( x ) } \rvert } $ converges.
- total convergence: for some sequence $ a $ of numbers, $ \sum \limits _ { n = 0 } ^ \infty a _ n $ converges and for each natural number $ n $, for each $ x \in I $, $ { \lvert f _ n { ( x ) } \rvert } \leq a _ n $.

Except that ‘normal’ is also called ‘total’, and you wonder whether they mean the same thing, and also what they're good for.

First of all, yes, they mean the same thing.  Suppose that the sequence is normally convergent, and let $ a _ n : = \sup _ { x \in I } { \lvert f _ n { ( x ) } \rvert } $.  Then with this sequence of numbers, the sequence of functions is totally convergent.  Conversely, suppose that the sequence is totally convergent.  Since $ \mathop \forall _ { x \in I } { \lvert f _ n { ( x ) } \rvert } \leq a _ n $, we also have $ \sup _ { x \in I } { \lvert f _ n { ( x ) } \rvert } \leq a _ n $, and now the sequence is normally convergent by a direct comparison.  This is good, since I'm not familiar with either term ‘normal’ or ‘total’ in this context, so I can't tell you which is the correct terminology; fortunately, I don't have to!

Although I'm not familiar with either terminology for it, however, I *am* familiar with the concept, which is the hypothesis for the Weierstrass M-Test (as mentioned by @interspazia in a comment).  This test (which gets its name from writing $ M _ n $ instead of $ a _ n $) states that if a series of functions is normally/totally convergent, then it is uniformly absolutely convergent.  (So this is a bit stronger than what you said, because we have that the series of absolute values converges uniformly as well.)  I don't know if the concept is useful in itself, beyond proving that a series is uniformly and absolutely convergent.  But since it involves just checking a single series of numbers (the series of suprema, or any convenient series of upper bounds), it is often handy.

There is [a Wikipedia article on normal convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence), but it doesn't really explain what's useful about it.  (It didn't even mention the M-Test until I edited it just now!)  However, it does at least give an example of a series that's uniformly convergent, even uniformly absolutely convergent, but not normally convergent:
$$ f _ n ( x ) = \cases { 1 / n & for $ x = 1 / n $, \\ 0 & for $ x \ne 1 / n $. } $$ (This could even be made into a series of smooth bump functions; the important thing is just that their supports should be disjoint.)

Comment: thank you very much; I still only have one question unanswered, if you could also answer this one you would really help me: what is the difference between uniform and normal convergence (not between total and normal)?

Comment: Well, anything that's uniformly convergent but not absolutely convergent (such as the the sequence $ f _ n ( x ) = ( - 1 ) ^ n / n $ of constant functions that converges to $ - \ln 2 $) won't be normally convergent.  I'll see if I can think of something that's absolutely uniformly convergent but not normally convergent.

Comment: By the way, I removed the bit at the end about sequences, because it was wrong.  If you start with a sequence of functions, turn it into a series, take the series of suprema, and turn that back into a sequence, you don't get the sequence of suprema of the original functions.  Sequences and series do correspond, so we still get a notion of normally convergent sequence of functions, but it's complicated to describe so probably not worth the bother.  And so I also put back some $ \sum _ { n = 0 } ^ \infty $ as well to shorten things.

Comment: Another example is $ f _ n ( x ) = ( - 1 ) ^ n x ^ { n \! } / n $ on $ I = { \mathopen ] 0 , 1 \mathclose [ } $ (the open interval). Then $ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty f _ n ( x ) $ converges uniformly on $ I $ to $ f ( x ) = - \ln ( 1 + x ) $, and the convergence is absolute since $ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty { | f _ n ( x ) | } $ converges to $ - \ln ( 1 - x ) $ for each $ x \in I $, but the series of suprema diverges (it's the harmonic series). However, this example fails to be *uniformly absolute*, because $ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty { | f _ n ( x ) | } $ doesn't converge uniformly on $ I $.

Comment: (I got this example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_absolute-convergence).)  Any normally convergent sequence will be uniformly absolute, since the sequence of absolute values has the same suprema and so is also normally convergent.  So it may be that normal convergence is equivalent to uniformly absolute convergence; but I don't yet know of a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: I should have looked on Wikipedia sooner since you gave me a name, because of course they have [an article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence).  So here's the example that's uniformly absolutely convergent but not normally convergent: $ f _ n ( x ) = [ x = 1 / n ] / n $ on $ I = [ 0 , 1 ] $, where $ [ x = 1 / n ] $ uses the Iverson bracket (so it's $ 1 $ if $ x = 1 / n $ and $ 0 $ otherwise).  Then $ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty { | f _ n ( x ) | } $ converges uniformly, but the sequence of suprema is the harmonic series again.

Comment: I put this example in the answer; the other examples are not so important since we have this one.

Comment: perfect, thank you again for both the examples. I also got to the conclusion that normal convergence is, at least in my university course, just an easier way (than using the definition) to prove that the series is uniformly convergent, but because of the mess on the various definitions/names and the fact that I’m not reading the *most complete* textbook on function series (just an introduction), I was wondering if I was missing something

Comment: I'm glad to have helped!